# Derive a ssreflect finType from a seq over a finType with uniq

Tags: coq, ssreflect

I have a structure consisting of a sequence over a finite type and a proof of uniq of this sequence. This should describe a type that is obviously finite, but I do not see how to show that.

I thought I could use UniqFinMixin, however it requires - if I understand this correctly - to provide an explicit seq of all elements of the type, which I don't know how to compute. I tried using Finite.enum on the finite type, but it only produces a seq with all the elements of the finite type and I didn't find an elegant way of computing all the subsequences / permutations.

```
From mathcomp
Require Import ssreflect ssrbool ssrfun eqtype ssrnat seq choice fintype.
From mathcomp
Require Import tuple finfun bigop finset.

Variable ft : finType.

Structure dbranch := {branch :> seq ft ; buniq : uniq branch}.

Canonical dbranch_subType := Eval hnf in [subType for branch].
Canonical dbranch_eqType := Eval hnf in EqType _ [eqMixin of dbranch by <:].
Canonical dbranch_choiceType := Eval hnf in ChoiceType _ [choiceMixin of dbranch by <:].
Canonical dbranch_countType := Eval hnf in CountType _ [countMixin of dbranch by <:].
Canonical dbranch_subCountType := Eval hnf in [subCountType of dbranch].


Lemma dbranchFin : Finite.mixin_of [eqType of dbranch].
Admitted. (* :-( *)

Canonical dbranch_finType := Eval hnf in FinType _ dbranchFin.
```

It seems weird to me that there wouldn't be a simple way to derive a finType here, but I couldn't find it in the finset.v file. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show that `dbranch` embeds into another `finType` -- for example, the type of lists of elements of `ft` whose size is bounded by `#|ft|`.

```
Lemma size_dbranch d : size (branch d) < #|ft|.+1.
Proof.
rewrite ltnS [card]unlock uniq_leq_size ?buniq // => ?.
by rewrite mem_enum.
Qed.

Definition tag_of_dbranch d : {k : 'I_#|ft|.+1 & k.-tuple ft} :=
  @Tagged _ (Sub (size (branch d)) (size_dbranch d))
            (fun k : 'I_#|ft|.+1 => k.-tuple ft)
            (in_tuple (branch d)).

Definition dbranch_of_tag (t : {k : 'I_#|ft|.+1 & k.-tuple ft}) : option dbranch :=
  insub (val (tagged t)).

Lemma tag_of_dbranchK : pcancel tag_of_dbranch dbranch_of_tag.
Proof. by rewrite /tag_of_dbranch /dbranch_of_tag=> x; rewrite valK. Qed.

Definition dbranch_finMixin := PcanFinMixin tag_of_dbranchK.
Canonical dbranch_finType := Eval hnf in FinType dbranch dbranch_finMixin.
```